# Spring app with JMS and Amazon SQS with security token expired

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I've done a simple project in Java Spring using JMSTemplate and AWS SQS service. The problem I have is related to the "expired token" I'm getting after AssumeRoleRequest, durationSecods has expired.

Let's see the configuration:
Here I'm using XML configuration because I'm working on some old "Spring" project.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.itam" />

<bean id="awsConfig" class="com.itam.AWSConfig">
    <property name="roleArn" value="arn:aws:iam::688566977937:role/nonprod-mbo-iam-approle-onprem"/>
    <property name="accessKey" value="********"/>
    <property name="secretsKey" value="************"/>
</bean>

<bean id="credentialsProviderBean" class="com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"/>
  
<bean id="connectionFactoryBuilder" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory$Builder">
    <property name="regionName" value="eu-west-1"/>
    <property name="numberOfMessagesToPrefetch" value="5"/> 
    <property name="awsCredentialsProvider" ref="AWSCustomProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory"
      factory-bean="connectionFactoryBuilder"
      factory-method="build"/>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" ref="queueName"/>
</bean>

<bean id="queueName" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="nonprod-mbo-sqs-api-hybridcollection-dev-mwcfgsend"/>
</bean>

<bean id="amazonMessageListener" class="com.itam.service.MyMessageConsumer" />

<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <property name="delegate" ref="amazonMessageListener"/>
    <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="onMessage"/>
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <null/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" ref="queueName" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

the "AWSCustomProvider" is a "Bean" which returns "AWSStaticCredentialsProvider" instance like:

```
@Bean(name="AWSCustomProvider")
    public AWSStaticCredentialsProvider getProvider() {
        System.out.println("getProvider: " + new Date());
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretsKey);
            AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder stsBuilder = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1);
            AWSSecurityTokenService sts = stsBuilder.build();
            AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                    .withRoleArn(roleArn)
                    .withDurationSeconds(900)
                    .withRoleSessionName("UBOPanelBridge");
            AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = sts.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
            BasicSessionCredentials temporaryCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(assumeResult.getCredentials()
            .getAccessKeyId(), assumeResult.getCredentials().getSecretAccessKey(), assumeResult.getCredentials()
            .getSessionToken());
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(temporaryCredentials);
    }
```

Here the token duration is set-up for 900 seconds.

Now in my "MyMessageConsumer" I receive a message from SQS like:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("MyMessageConsumer")
public class MyMessageConsumer {
    
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        try {
            System.out.println("Received message "+ textMessage.getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing message " + e.toString() );
        }
    }
     
}
```

The problem I have is that when a token is expired I get an exception like:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: ExpiredToken; Request ID: ee668a92-e3da-5d0f-908f-d3d9291ccb3d)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1695)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1350)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1101)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:758)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:732)
```

The question is what is the "way" to re-initialize the token used in the SQSConnectionFactory? What is the best or prefered technique to re-new the token using the Spring framework? How to properly handle this situation with the expired token?

Thank you for any information,

Peter

Comment: Are you going to host this service in AWS itself?

Comment: Currently no.. It is a standalone JBoss server running outside AWS..

Comment: Ok I'll update the answer

Comment: Is there maybe an option to periodically check the token expiration value and "reinitialize" it when it is expired and save it in the spring context with the same name? (it is not the way I would like to code or solve the problem but...)

Answer (score 0):

Including credentials like this in code is not a good practice. If you are deploying this Java service to AWS cloud, you don't need to have credentials hard coded like this. You can use IAM roles. For example let's say you deploy this service to an EC2 instance, if you give required SQS permission to that instance's IAM role, AWS will allow the relevant SQS actions from that instance. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). This applies to any service whether it's EC2, Lambda, etc. all resources on AWS can have an IAM role with permission to access other AWS services.

On the other hand if you just want to test this in your local machine you do need to have the credentials. In my opinion easiest way is to use global AWS credential file for your machine rather than hard coding them in every application. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

Comment: Currently no.. I have an old JBoss running somewhere outside AWS.. also credentials will be stored in standalone-full.xml.. This example I have provided is just to have an idea..

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem using STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider (AWSCredentialsProvider implementation that uses the AWS Security Token Service to assume a Role and create temporary, short-lived sessions to use for authentication. This credentials provider uses a background thread to refresh credentials).

```
public AWSCredentialsProvider getProvider() {
         AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretsKey));
         AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentialsProvider).withRegion("eu-west-1").build();   
         AWSCredentialsProvider temporaryCredentials = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider
                .Builder(roleArn, APP_NAME)
                .withStsClient(stsClient)
                .withRoleSessionDurationSeconds(SESSION_TIME)
                .build();
         return temporaryCredentials;
    }
```

Thanks to Nejc Ravnik for the suggestion.